# Minecraft Server Admin: Regions vs Logging

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I've run a little minecraft server for my friends for almost a year. I've started experiencing griefing and installed bukkit and the plugin CoreProtect, which logs block place/breakage.

It's great. However, the cost is increased CPU usage, which severely limits the amount of players. I'm running on Dual core @ 2.4 Ghz and 2 gig ram with ubuntu server installed. I run out of CPU on 8 players now.

What is more CPU intensive: Regions protection or block logging? Will storing logs in Flat Files or MySQL be more intensive on ram and CPU? Is their any difficulties with using regions such as user learning curve?  Is there a more lightweight plugin to log block placing/breakage than CoreProtect?

Thanks to anyone who can provide any info.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange Gaming. This question does not seem to be reasonably scoped as per [the FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). Perhaps you could consider narrowing down the question or breaking it into multiple questions. Also, it's not really a question. "I was just wondering about...," "I also want to know about...," and "I'm also wondering..." are all very unspecific and hard to answer. What are you looking for as answers to these? Some sort of discrete numbers for how it affects CPU/RAM? What do you want to know about the admin side? etc.

Answer (score 3):

CoreProtect is multi-threaded. Bukkit isn't. You have a dual core processor.

What this means is that although Bukkit will be restricted to a single core, CoreProtect can do all file logging on the second core.

This means that server performance will not be impacted at all when using CoreProtect.

-Intelli / CoreProtect Dev

Comment: Thanks! What has a better performance: Flat files or MySQL?

Comment: File based storage will ultimately have better performance and use less disk space.

Comment: @Intelli [citation needed]. Isn't the point of MySQL to be compact and fast? I doubt that flatfiles can surpass MySQL on a large scale.